# return shell_exec then preg_match

Tags: return, preg-match, preg-match-all, shell-exec

Here's something pretty weird:

```
$txt = '/some/dir/some/file.txt';
$content = shell_exec('cat "'.$txt.'"');
```

then:

```
preg_match_all("![some regex]!", $content, $matches);
```

but then preg_match returns nothing/false since $content "seems" empty (while it's actually a txt file being filled with some infos: the wget output of a download in progress).

weird thing is, if i do:

```
echo $content; exit;
```

it perfectly shows the current content of my txt file. when i F5/refresh, the content is accurately updated and print again. But preg_match still can't parse it...

```
$content = shell_exec('cat "'.$txt.'"' 2>&1);
```

isn't doing better.

NB: path to file is correct, chmod is correct, etc...

I even tried the following:

```
$content = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$txt, true);
```

or

```
$ch_txt = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch_txt, CURLOPT_URL, dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$txt);
curl_setopt($ch_txt, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch_txt, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch_txt);
curl_close($ch_txt);
```

And same behaviour goes on!

I've never seen something that funny.

Additionnal info:

the regex is:

```
preg_match_all("!([0-9A-Za-z]+)([ \.]+)([0-9]+)% ([0-9\.A-Za-z]+) ([0-9a-zA-Z]+)!", $content, $matches);
```

the file content is like:

```
323600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  114K 36m48s
323650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  249K 36m47s
323700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  116K 36m47s
323750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  242K 36m47s
323800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  114K 36m46s
323850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  237K 36m46s
```

output of this:

```
system("wget '".$file_to_download."' --load-cookies=".$directory."cookie.txt --output-document='".$directory.$new_directory."/".$output."' -P ".$directory." --output-file='".$directory.$output.".txt' -b >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

Comment: Can you provide the regex and the file? If you change the regex to `.*`, does it work?

Comment: I see what you mean mate, and i feel very bad! edit: well actually the regex looks ok :s I'll edit first post in a few with additionnal info.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("!([0-9A-Za-z]+)([ \.]+)([0-9]+)%([ ]+)([0-9\.A-Za-z]+) ([0-9a-zA-Z]+)!", $content, $matches);
```